# Inline Styling and html-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, background-image, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using a template file with `html-webpack-plugin`. Up until now, I've used `img` tags for my images in the template and `file-loader` has handled them fine. But if I try to set the background image of an element inline, `file-loader` is not triggered and the image is not moved into my build folder.

Piece of the template file in question:

```
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url('assets/imgs/Portfolio/AFTO.png')"></div> // This image is not loaded
<div class="slide">
    <img src="assets/imgs/Portfolio/BTB.png" alt=""> // This image is loaded fine, hash and all
</div>
```

webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack'),
      path = require("path"),
      fs = require("fs"),
      Inject = require('webpack-inject-plugin').default, { ENTRY_ORDER } = require('webpack-inject-plugin'),
      HtmlWebpack = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
      { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './js/app.js'),
    output: {
        filename: "app.[contentHash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./build")
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './build'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|svg)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'imgs'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|eot|ttf)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'fonts'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            // global utils
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        }),
        new Inject(() => fs.readFileSync('./js/vendor/t.js-master/t.js', {encoding: 'utf-8'}), {
            entryOrder: ENTRY_ORDER.Last
        }),
        new HtmlWebpack({
            template: 'template.html'
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({ cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false })
    ]
}
```

I'm surprised by this, because I thought webpack looks for urls to files, not html tags. Is there a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a way that you can achieve you goal by just simply using interpolation syntax of `html-webpack-plugin` without having to using `html-loader` (likely getting conflicted).

Here's the few steps:

- Change your template to use interpolation syntax to require the image:

```js
<div style="background-image: url(<%= require('assets/imgs/Portfolio/AFTO.png') %>" />
```

- Disable `esModule` options of `file-loader` to make `require` function work without having to `.default`:

`webpack.config.js`

```js
{
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    // ...
    esModule: false,
  }  
}
```

- Finally, we might need to remove `html-loader` to avoid interpolation syntax not getting compiled

Comment: That worked! just had to add a `./` for the require to work. Are the `<%= %>` tags specific to this plugin or should I know about them from somewhere else? The [documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options) mentions them but doesn't really explain. Thank you again.

Comment: If you stop using `html-loader`, the `ejs-loader` will be used by default which is using lodash template here https://lodash.com/docs/#template