# webpack 5 url-loader /file-loader or asset/resources for inline style url(image') not working

Tags: css, image, webpack

I have html file where using background-image:url('../relative/path') and but it is not loading while using same path in  it is working fine.

I have tried with url-loader, file-loader, asset/resources asset/inline but none of them is working with various combination of options .

this is the basic html

```html
<img src="../assets/images/fruits/lemon.png" />
<div style="background-image:url('../assets/images/fruits/lemon.png'); height: 20rem; width: 20rem; border: 1px solid red;">
image div
</div>
```

here is my webpack module config

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path = require("path");

const modules = {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.html$/i,
      loader: "html-loader"
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
          loader: "css-loader",
          options: {
            importLoaders: 2,
            url: true,
            esModule: true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|gif)$/,
      type: "asset/inline",
      dependency: { not: ["url"] },
      use: {
        loader: "url-loader"
      }
    },

    {
      test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
      type: "asset/resource",
      dependency: { not: ["url"] },
      generator: {
        filename: "assets/fonts/[hash][ext][query]"
      }
    }
  ]
};

module.exports = modules;
```

what coule be wrong here?
note: not copying any images in dist folder  and also in dev toll the image type is text/html for background-image location while img tag automatically converted to some hash image path

[image]

Comment: Might [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65401669/inline-styling-and-html-webpack-plugin) be useful?

Comment: Thanks but not helping as it says to change in html file which will cause more problem in build and also saying to remove html-loader